# from json to a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, json

I can go one way using

```
require 'json'

def saveUserLib(user_lib)
    File.open("/Users/name/Documents/user_lib.json","w") do |f|
    f.write($user_lib.to_json)
    end
end

uname = gets.chomp
$user_lib["_uname"] = uname
saveUserLib($user_lib)
```

but how do i get it back again as my user_lib?

Comment: Small code criticism: you should not hardcode the file path into your method. You should either have your method accept a file path, or put a constant at the top of your file with the path to use. Rule of thumb (there are always exceptions): if you ever hard code a number (other than perhaps 1) or user-facing string inside a method, you're making your code more fragile and harder to maintain.

Comment: when I remove my `$`'s I get the following error: `<main>': undefined local variable or method `user_lib' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: but about the path - this i am aware - but it was for a quick test! thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You want [`JSON.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) or [`JSON.load`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load):

```
def load_user_lib( filename )
  JSON.parse( IO.read(filename) )
end
```

The key here is to use `IO.read` as a simple way to load the JSON string from disk, so that it can be parsed. Or, if you have UTF-8 data in your file:

```
  my_object = JSON.parse( IO.read(filename, encoding:'utf-8') )
```

I've linked to the JSON documentation above, so you should go read that for more details. But in summary:

- `json = my_object.to_json` — method on the specific object to create a JSON string.
- `json = JSON.generate(my_object)` — create JSON string from object.
- `JSON.dump(my_object, someIO)` — create a JSON string and write to a file.
- `my_object = JSON.parse(json)` — create a Ruby object from a JSON string.
- `my_object = JSON.load(someIO)` — create a Ruby object from a file.

Alternatively:

```
def load_user_lib( filename )
  File.open( filename, "r" ) do |f|
    JSON.load( f )
  end
end
```

*Note: I have used a "snake_case" name for the method corresponding to your "camelCase" `saveUserLib` as this is the Ruby convention.*

Comment: what is the difference between `JSON.dump` / `.to_json` / `JSON.generate` and then `JSON.parse` / `JSON.load` ?

Comment: @user969617 I've edited my answer to show the difference, and summarize the ways of dealing with JSON data.

Comment: Both `JSON.parse` and `JSON.load` can "create a Ruby object from a JSON string"

Comment: As this is the top answer, I think you should correct the JSON.parse call to `JSON.parse(IO.read(filename))`

Comment: @walfish3d But of course, and thanks. (You're also welcome in the future to edit someone else's answer when such an obvious mistake has been made. ;)

Comment: Contrary to what you may expect, you get stuff like `user['name']` not `user[:name]`

Answer (score 2):

here is some example:

```
require 'json'

source_hash = {s: 12, f: 43}
json_string = JSON.generate source_hash
back_to_hash = JSON.parse json_string
```

Comment: Not true! `JSON.parse` result is string-full as `{"s"=>12, "f"=>43}` not `{s: 12, f: 43}`

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.load` will do the trick. Here's an example that goes both ways:

```
>> require 'json'
=> true
>> a = {"1" => "2"}
=> {"1"=>"2"}
>> b = JSON.dump(a)
=> "{\"1\":\"2\"}"
>> c = JSON.load(b)
=> {"1"=>"2"}
```