# Output json once its in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing a JSON string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

I've managed to get a bunch of json into a variable in ruby and print it out, through the JSON gem and the following code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("https://api.pinboard.in/v1/posts/get?auth_token=username:token&tag=fashion&meta=yes&format=json").read)
puts result
```

What it returns is this:

```
{
  "date"=>"2012-09-24T03:35:38Z",
  "user"=>"username",
  "posts"=>[{
      "href"=>"http://example.com/example.jpg",
      "description"=>"this is the description",
      "extended"=>"A full, longer description.",
      "meta"=>"d6f967c9adfbe1eb3763fddbcd993d1b",
      "hash"=>"a46e0e7202d9d56c516a472d8be70d9e",
      "time"=>"2012-09-24T03:35:38Z",
      "shared"=>"yes",
      "toread"=>"no",
      "tags"=>"fashion"
    }
]}
```

(the line-spacing here is mine, for clarity)

My problem is, I have *no idea* how to access these keys and values! I've googled and searched but I'm really new to ruby and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out exactly *what* I'm supposed to be doing, nevermind the code to do it. Help?

Comment: This has nothing to do with json. It is about accessing values within a hash.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9055096/128421.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result["date"]` - accesses the date key on the json.

In general `result[<key>]` accesses the value stored in key.

If you try to access a key that does not exists you will get nil as a result.

Edit: In order to traverse the key/value pairs you can:

```
result.each do |key, value|
   puts "result[#{key}] = #{value}"
end
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's embarrassing for me. Thanks! How would I grab the name of the key itself, say if I wanted to loop through all the keys and values and print each key name next to its value?

Comment: You'd use `Hash.keys`, but before that you'd read through [Ruby's documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html) about accessing [arrays](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) and [hashes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) which covers all this.

Answer (score 0):

Do stuff like:

```
p result["date"]
p result["posts"].size
```

Look up the documentation for the ruby Array and Hash classes.