# Check if a favorited tweet contains a URL within the body

Tags: ruby, json, twitter

Building a small app and would like to return all a users favorited tweets. This is easy enough to do with the twitter gem. I would then like to further filter the returned results by only displaying the favorited tweets that contain a URL within the body.

Now as I understand it Using the the twitter gem running `Twitter.favorites` will return a json of all the favorited tweets. Now within each of the individual tweets it returns a entity property that contains a URL hash this will be empty if no URL is present in the tweet and a URL if one is present.

How would I implement a check to say if the URL is present then display tweet. I'm a noob with json and Apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used the `twitter` gem, but since the question remains unanswered for a couple of hours, I’ll try to do my best.

First of all the gem seems to return [`Array<Twitter::Tweet>`](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API/Favorites#favorites-instance_method) rather than raw json. So you only need to filter the array:

```
favs_with_urls = Twitter.favorites.reject { |r| r.urls.empty }
```

The latter should do the trick.

BTW, if you for some reason need to [parse `json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055096/from-json-to-a-ruby-hash) to a hash:

```
require 'json'
c = JSON.load(raw_json)
```