# Can't get values from json stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra-activerecord

I'm trying to write app which logs json msgs to db. That part I got. The problem comes with getting that json back. I can't get values from it.
I've tried to get raw msgs from db and getting values from this ( json gem seems not to see it as json)
I've tried to parse it via .to_json , but it doesn't seem to work either. Maby you have some idea how to get it?
Thanks in advance

table:

```
mjl_pk  bigserial
mjl_body    text <- JSON is stored here
mjl_time    timestamp
mjl_issuer  varchar
mjl_status  varchar
mjl_action  varchar
mjl_object  varchar
mjl_pat_id  varchar
mjl_stu_id  varchar
```

code:

```
#Include config catalog, where jsonadds is
$LOAD_PATH << 'config'

#Requirements
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'json'
require 'jsonadds'
require 'RestClient'

#Class for db
class Mjl < ActiveRecord::Base
#table name
  self.table_name = "msg_json_log"
#serialization
  serialize :properties, JSON
#overwrite ActiveRecord id with "mjl_pk"
  def self.primary_key
    "mjl_pk"
  end
end

#Get json msg and write it to db
post '/logger' do
  content_type :json
#Check if msg is json
  if JSON.is_json?(params[:data])
#insert data into db
    msg = Mjl.create(:mjl_body => params[:data] ,:mjl_issuer => 'LOGGER', :mjl_action => 'test', :mjl_object =>'obj')
  else
#else return error    
    puts "Not a JSON \n" + params[:data]
  end
end

#Get json with id = params[:id]
get '/json/:id' do
  content_type :json
#Get json from db
  json_body = Mjl.where(mjl_pk: params[:id]).pluck(:mjl_body)
  puts json_body
  json_body = json_body.to_json
  puts json_body
#Get 'patientData' from json
  puts json_body['key']
  puts json_body[0]['key']
end
```

Output:

```
{
"key": "I am a value",
"group": {
  "key2": "Next value",
  "key3": "Another one"
  },
  "val1": "Val"
}
["{\n    \"key\": \"I am a value\",\n    \"group\": {\n        \"key2\": \"Next value\",\n        \"key3\": \"Another one\"\n    },\n    \"val1\": \"Val\"\n}"]
key
 <--empty value from 'puts json_body[0]['key']'
```

Comment: Which database are you using? PostgreSQL in 9.3 has JSON datatype, so you dont need to serialize.

Comment: I'm using postgresql and I've tried it. But seems like activerecord does not get it. It's returning empty value, when im getting it from db. Unlessofcourse im doing something wrong. (I was using same code as above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found how to do it. 
I saw explanation on JSON methods at:
[from json to a ruby hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055096/from-json-to-a-ruby-hash/9055150#9055150) 
Code which works for me:

```
  json_body = Mjl.where(mjl_pk: params[:id]).pluck(:mjl_body)
  puts json_body
  jparsed = JSON.parse(json_body[0])
  puts jparsed['key']
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also created a JSON Log in my project like this, this might help you...

**In Controller**

```
current_time = Time.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
@status_log = {}
@arr = {}
@arr[:status_id] = "2.1"
@arr[:status_short_desc] = "Order confirmed"
@arr[:status_long_desc] = "Order item has been packed and ready for shipment"
@arr[:time] = current_time
@status_log[2.1] = @arr
@status_log_json = JSON.generate(@status_log)
StoreStock.where(:id => params[:id]).update_all(:status_json => @status_log_json)
```

**In View**

```
@json_status = JSON.parse(ps.status_json)  # ps.status_json contails raw JSON Log

= @json_status['2.1']['status_long_desc']
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing

```
json_body = Mjl.where(mjl_pk: params[:id]).pluck(:mjl_body)
```

you already have json
so no need doing

```
 json_body = json_body.to_json
```

Since doing this you get the string representation of json, just remove that line and you will get all the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I've tried that eariel (json_body['key']) and i've got:
no implicit conversion of String into Integer error

Comment: can you provide the full error message stack, or point on which line does it happen?

Comment: Sure:
    C:/Users/r.leszczynski/workspace/nauka/app.rb in []
       puts json_body['key'] 
     C:/Users/r.leszczynski/workspace/nauka/app.rb in block in <main>
       puts json_body['key']
     C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
       proc { |a,p| unbound_method.bind(a).call }
I've put it after
    json_body = Mjl.where(mjl_pk: params[:id]).pluck(:mjl_body)